# Setting double integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Integrate $f(x,y,z)=y$ over the region $x=0,y=0,z=0, 2x+2y+z=4$

Will the double integral be of the form $\int_0 ^4 \int_y^{4-2y}ydydz$?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this is a triple integral: when $\;0\le x\le 2\;$ , we have $\;0\le y\le -x+2\;$ , and then $\;0\le z\le4-2x-2y\;$ , so the integral is

$$\int_0^2\int_0^{-x+2}\int_0^{4-2x-2y}ydzdydx=\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}y(4-2x-2y)dydx=$$

$$=\int_0^2\left((2-x)y^2-\frac23y^3\right)_0^{2-x}dx=\int_0^2\left[(2-x)(x-2)^2-\frac23(2-x)^3\right]dx=...$$

Try to complete the calculations.

Comment: Joan, this was my interpretation also.  +1  -Mark